# RelativeLayout place two containers one above the another - Android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Can someone tell me if this is possible? I have a `RelativeLayout` and I want to display two `FrameLayout`s, one above the another. The one that I want it to be at the bottom, has a `width` attribute set to `wrap_content`, and the other should take all the space of its parent above.

This is what I have, and it's not working. The problem is that the layout above is not displayed, only the one at the bottom.

Here is my code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/upper_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/down_container" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/down_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: in the second framlayout change   android:id="@+id/down_container" with   android:id="@id/down_container"

Comment: Using `LinearLayout` would be better for this.

Comment: LinearLayout how?? I don't have a fixed height for neither of the FrameLayout's..

Answer (score 1):

change android:layout_above="@+id/down_container" to android:layout_above="@id/down_container"

@+id/ is use for create id and @id/ is use for give the reference of this particular component.

Comment: That gives me errors: "No resource found that matches the given name", regarding the down_container

Comment: <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/down_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip" />                                                         <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/upper_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/down_container" >
    </FrameLayout> Chage this with your code, that gives you no error....

Comment: When changing like this, my upper container is displayed across the full screen, and now my down container is gone. We can't do it like this. It has to be in that order

Comment: change attribute  android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap_content" of upper container.. Your upper container take whole place of your screen